# ASP.NET MVC CTP5 Crashing IDE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, ide, crash, preview-5

I've recently installed the MVC CTP5 and VS is now crashing on me when I try to open an aspx, I get the following error in event viewer:

```
.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3053 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A035E00) (80131506)
```

I was able to find [This](http://forums.asp.net/t/1313452.aspx) post on the asp.net forums relating to the same issue but nobody has had a working solution yet (at least not for me).

Just wondering if anyone else has run into this issue and what they have done to resolve it?

EDIT: Wanted to add that I have tried all the tips in the article and can open the markup with a code editor but was wondering an actual solution had been found to resolve this issue.. Thanks!

EDIT: I don't have this issue on my Vista box, seems to only occur on my XP VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a problem with Power Commands and Preview 5. If you have Power Commands installed, try updating or uninstalling it to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a steps to work around from **the post** that work for me:

1.Open project based on CTP5

2.IN solution Explorer, enable "Show All files"

3.Open "bin" folder and delete "Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll", "System.Web.Mvc.dll", "System.Web.Abstractions.dll", "System.Web.Routing.dll"

4.Open "References" folder, click ONCE "System.Web.Abstractions" and in Properties window change "Copy Local" to true. Repeat same with System.Web.Routing.

5.Build application (Ctrl+Shift+B)

6.Open site.master in designer. VS will not crash.

Comment: That didn't do the trick for me but I think i'm going to try all the solutions from the article again just to make sure i'm not crazy.

Answer (score 2):

FYI - Microsoft has released a hotfix that fixes [at least some variations of] this problem:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=16827&wa=wsignin1.0

http://blogs.msdn.com/jnak/archive/2009/02/26/fix-available-asp-net-mvc-rc-crash-in-a-windows-azure-cloud-service-project.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a null answer but I’ve been having this too. Not that I restart VS often but cleaning out the bin folder before opening the web project is my workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Have same problem, on vista x64 and vs2008 sp1. Have to do probably something with cleaning bin folder and system.web.routing/abstraction, because it crashes even on webforms project with (mvc) routing in it. When I delete all files from bin, and add references again, it works fine.
Really annoying bug in vs2008+ctp5!