# Troubleshooting Visual Studio 2008 crash when loading a solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I've downloaded the source for SubSonic via SVN. When I try to open the project in Visual Studio 2008, it converts the solution, loads all the projects then disappears without an error message. Subsequent loads of the solution do the same. If I run devenv /safemode and then open the project it works fine, but I can't use any add-ins.

Any ideas for tracking down the crash?

Edit: In event viewer:

```
    Event Type: Error
    Event Source:   .NET Runtime Event
    Category:   None 
    Event ID:   1023
    Date:       10/23/2008 
    Time:       4:45:05 PM  
    User:       N/A 
    Computer:   Foo 
    Description: .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3053 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A035E00) (80131506)
```

Comment: no entries in event log?

Comment: Good point...i'll check and update the post

Comment: That error code led me to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134131/aspnet-mvc-ctp5-crashing-ide (trying it now)

Comment: yeah looks like an addin problem. worth troubleshooting with procmon to nail down the exact addin.

Comment: I'm getting exact same error (same event log entry) without PowerCommands installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like this issue is reported:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=34

Answer (score 3):

This was a conflict with PowerCommands (see [ASP.NET MVC CTP5 Crashing IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134131/aspnet-mvc-ctp5-crashing-ide))